# Loading a GIF file into CGImage

Tags: cocoa, macos, cgimage

obviously both creation functions for PNG and JPEG doesn't help for GIF files,
How is it possible (and easy?) to load a gif file into a CGImage.

Answer (score 3):

For a Mac, the easiest way is:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"mygif.gif"];
CGImageRef myCGImage = [[NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData: data] CGImage];
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using Mac Cocoa, and not Cocoa Touch, so I don't have UIImage

Comment: Isn't the `dataWithContentsOfFile:` method only receive absolute file paths?

Comment: Yes and no. A relative path can be used, but since you rarely set your working directory on OS X or iOS, it becomes a question of "relative to what?" In this case, it was just a placeholder for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Building on JG's answer, for reference.

A solid way to get the "name" of the file is:

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"];
```

And then continue with JG's solution:

```
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([fileName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
self.maskedImage = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```